# Angular.js: set default selected from ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I have an angular.js single page app, with initial data gathered from a rest endpoint.

This app gets a list of IDs representing a saved models, as well as a tree of options to populate some cascading dropdowns.

How can I set the default path in the tree based on my IDs from the model?

Some illustrative code:

Models:

```
DefaultOptions = [
    {"Id" : 044},
    {"Id" : 142},
    {"Id" : 244}
];

OptionsTree = [
    {"Text" : "Option1",
     "subOptions" : [
          {"Text" : "SubOption1", "Id" : 044},
          {"Text" : "SubOption2", "Id" : 142}
      ]},
    {"Text" : "Option2",
     "subOptions" : [
          {"Text" : "SubOptionA", "Id" : 3033},
          {"Text" : "SubOptionB", "Id" : 244}
      ]}
];
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="member in DefaultOptions">
    <select ng-model="option" 
            ng-options="o as o.Text for o in OptionsTree">
    </select>

    <select ng-model="subOption" 
            ng-options="s as s.Text for s in option.subOptions"
            ng-disabled="!option" 
            ng-change="member.Id = subOption.Id">
    </select>
</div>
```

This HTML will properly update the DefaultOptions ID if the user selects a new one, but cannot set the default. What am I missing?

Comment: do you want to have only the Id in your ``subOption`` model or the whole object with 'Text' and 'Id'?

Comment: Whole object (some of my dropdowns are four or five levels deep). The terminal cascading dropdown (in this case the last one with the ID) can just have only the ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selects' `ng-model` to account for the `ng-repeat`:

Then put this in your controller:

```
// Main dropdown
$scope.member.option = OptionsTree[0];
```

and then:

```
// Sub dropdown
$scope.member.subOption = OptionsTree[0].subOptions[0].id
```

Since your question didn't state if you wanted the id or the whole object I assumed the whole object for the main dropdown and just the id for the sub dropdown.

Comment: The complication (at least to my angular noob eyes) is that this is in an ng-repeat with three items (DefaultOptions is a list with 3 members). How do I handle the fact that ng-repeat creates a subscope, with each sub scope having it's own option and subOption?

Comment: @jaypb Use ng-model="member.option" and ng-model="member.subOption"